# How to take Count (*) as variable from SQL to php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have made request to SQL:

```
SELECT meta_value,  COUNT(*)  from wp_postmeta;
```

and have in respond an array:

```
array (size=102)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[24]
      public 'meta_value' => string '37' (length=2)
      public 'COUNT(*)' => string '147' (length=3)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[23]
      public 'meta_value' => string '32' (length=2)
      public 'COUNT(*)' => string '143' (length=3)
```

I take "meta_value" without any troubles with php code:

```
$result->meta_value;
```

But how take values of public **'COUNT(*)'** => string '143' (length=3)? 
I have tried different syntaxis and some errors only.

*I need values: 147,143...*

Comment: `SELECT meta_value,  COUNT(*) as xy  from wp_postmeta;` does that do the trick for you?

Comment: Nice, wrote a answer (Also if you want to read up on that it's called an alias name! You can do that with everything you select (e.g. `SELECT name as xy from table where id = 1`))

Comment: Yes. thank you. I have read SQL for Dummiers before and have not remembered this thing. It is really simple. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `AS` to create an alias

```
SELECT meta_value,  COUNT(*) As count  from wp_postmeta;
```

then use `count`

Comment: It is called an alias name

Answer (score 5):

Use the alias `AS` in your SQL to give the MySQL function a desired name.

```
SELECT meta_value,  COUNT(*) as counter from wp_postmeta;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT meta_value,  COUNT(*) AS total  from wp_postmeta;
```

This is good solution.

But you can do it alternative way(if you want to keep your query as it is)

```
$total="count(*)";//keep it inside a variable;
//now you can use it

$result->$total;
```

`$result->count(*)` will produce syntax error but `$result->$total;` will work

Answer (score 1):

You can use a alias name with `AS` like this:

```
SELECT meta_value, COUNT(*) as xy from wp_postmeta;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT meta_value,COUNT(*) AS total_count FROM wp_postmeta

echo $result->total_count;
```